# Cryptic threat names

Tags: network, ids, threat-mitigation

I have logs from a security appliance from Damballa which has cryptic names for threats observed in a network which I am trying to make sense of. Some examples of these threats are "RedTreeBruisers" , "WeirdSideTroop" , "WhiteBikeScorpions" ,etc. which I do not know how to interpret . I have over a 100 of these unique threat names with 3 words concatenated together. Unfortunately I don't have access to documentation / otherwise for this appliance. Any ideas what these threats mean & Is this a standard of some sort? What would be the best way to decode them?

Comment: you might want to add the make/model/version of the security appliance in question, in case someone who does have access to the docs sees this question and might be able to help.

Comment: Since the names you quote don't appear on the Internet (All Praises to Mighty Google !), one may infer that the names are automatically generated and represent some sort of three-symbol code. This may be a method for the appliance vendor to somehow ensure that customers will use his services to make sense of the data.

Comment: When you say these are the "names," are these the names of the files or processes, the names of the programs, the names of the services listening on the TCP ports, etc? Or does the log not say?

Comment: These are the names of the "threats" that the appliance detected by observing traffic on the network

Answer (score 2):

The appliance is obviously using arbitrary names to name/describe those threats.

Vendors often use such home-made naming/description conventions. For example:

- [Symantec Virus Naming Convention](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/virusnaming.jsp)
- [Avira Malware Naming Convention](http://www.avira.com/en/support-malware-naming-conventions)

And you can also find naming/description standards from the academic world or standard organizations, for example:

- [MITRE MAEC](http://maec.mitre.org/) (standardized language for encoding and communicating
  high-fidelity information about malware based upon attributes such as
  behaviors, artifacts, and attack patterns)
- [IETF RFC 5070](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5070.txt) (Incident Object Description Exchange Format)

Sometimes on those appliances you can find additional information in the detailed view that gives you the "official" name and variant of the detected threat.